# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pox

I am writing TRW algorithm in POX controller using python where i am assigning a time period to a host first time a sender is sending actually TRW algorithm says that first packet sent from internal host to external host will sent to destination without installing any flow rule hence i have wrtn a function to do that as

```
localhostrecord{}
class FCC_Queue_Entry (object):
"""this class object will be kept into FCC_Queue list of IntHostEntry class object"""
 whenInitiated=0
 dip=0
 status=0
 protocol=0
def __init__ (self,whenInitiated,dip,status,protocol):
  self.whenInitiated = whenInitiated
  self.dip = dip
  self.status = status
  self.protocol = protocol
```

and

```
class IntHostEntry (object):
 likelihood=0.0
 credit=0
 zeroCreditTime=0
 PCH=[]
FCC_Queue=[]
```

"""PCH keeps all host address which has been previously contacted with receiver"""
  """ keeps object of FCC_Queue_Entry class"""

```
 def __init__ (self,likelihood,credit,zeroCreditTime):
 self.likelihood = likelihood
 self.credit = credit
 self.zeroCreditTime = zeroCreditTime
```

after that i have written code to send packet as

```
def send_Packet(event, ip_packet, ip_protocol, dpidstr, buffer_id, src_port, out_port): 
  src = ip_packet.srcip
  dst = ip_packet.dstip
  if src not in localhostrecord:
    log.info("local host %s is sending for the firsr time" %(src))
    t = datetime.time(0, 0, 0)  
    newIntHost = IntHostEntry(1.0,10,t.second)
    localhostrecord[src] = newIntHost

  if dst not in localhostrecord[src].PCH:
    localhostrecord[src].PCH.append(dst)
    newEntry = FCC_Queue_Entry(time.clock(),dst,status[0],ip_protocol)
    localhostrecord[src].FCC_Queue.append(newEntry)
```

,after sometime i am checking for timeout using

```
if(time.clock() - localhostrecord[address].FCC_Queue[index].whenInitiated>=timeout):
```

where

```
localhostrecord[address].FCC_Queue[index].whenInitiated =time.clock()
```

written in some other function

i am getting error saying

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

how to solve that problem

Comment: Please insert `print localhostrecord[address].FCC_Queue[index].whenInitiated` before the statement and see what it shows.

Comment: I understand the error message. But i don't understand your question. Can you please improve your question? How is whenInitiated wrote in other function? May be you have forgot `()` after calling of function `time.clock` somewhere

Comment: yeah you are right actually i have forgot to write () after time.clock thank you @julivico

Answer (score 0):

What python is telling you is that you are trying to use the `-` operator on a `float` (your `time.clock()`) and on an uncalled `function` (`localhostrecord[address].FCC_Queue[index].whenInitiated`)

Make sure to call your function to use it's return value (note the `()` at the end of `whenInititated`):

```
if(time.clock() - localhostrecord[address].FCC_Queue[index].whenInitiated()) >=timeout:
```